# MongoDb select different object types in collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection called Users. 
I do not know object types in advance.
This collection has at least 3 different type structured of objects. For example:

Type 1:

```
{
"_id" : "9e1736d4-f3a1-47ed-bb51-3318129664f0",
"userid" : 6711,
"registerDate" : "2014-10-28T14:42:06",
"lastLoginDate" : "2014-10-28T14:42:06",

}
```

Type 2:

```
{
"_id" : "9e1736d4-f3a1-47ed-bb51-3318129664f1",
"userid" : 6712,
"email" : "johndoe@example.com",
"username" : "john doe",

}
```

Type 3:

```
{
"_id" : "9e1736d4-f3a1-47ed-bb51-3318129664f2",
"userid" : 63713,
"city" : "orange",
"state" : "new york",
"country" : "US",
}
```

How can I get distinct types (or top 1st object from each type) from my collection?
So if I have 1 million users and 3 different structure above, I would like to get 3 results.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field "type" identifing type of the document.
Then use [db.collection.group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/) to group results on your wish.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have modify rights on the database, read-only. I just cannot do it by query?

Comment: There is no efficient way to do it regarding million users. If you can create a new collection, you can make a surrogate "type" field in a new collection via MAP by concating sorted names of fields of document, then group by this field. You still need some `type` field, but you can do it creating a new collection.
But it is highly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Issue query for each type, you may

```
db.c.findOne({registerDate: {$existed: true}});
db.c.findOne({email: {$existed: true}});
db.c.findOne({city: {$existed: true}});
```

This should be very fast and simple. :)

Comment: thanks but the problem is I do not know object types in advance :)

Comment: @Teoman shipahi, Oh my god. A clear definition for difference is required, then.

Comment: I will add it in description.

Comment: @Teoman shipahi: I think it's hard based on your limited information. For example, {a:1} is the 1st type, {a:1, b:2} is the 2nd type, {a:1, b:{a:1, b:2}} is the 3rd type, etc. You have to retrieve the entire document and make an identical structure comparison which is very inefficient in 1 million space. But as examples you provided, a clue that no intersection between any two type on fields, which will be more efficient. This is only my opinion, and maybe someone can share other efficient way to help.